# AAPT: error: attribute android:margin_Bottom not found

Tags: java, xml, firebase-realtime-database, aapt

I am creating a simple login apps and have used Firebase Realtime Database to store the username, password and phone. For XML design part I have used LinearLayout and it also has margin_Bottom, but for some reason when I run the code it says 'AAPT: error: attribute android:margin_Bottom not found'.
Here is the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.communicationappbounceback.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:margin_Bottom="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center">


    <EditText
         android:layout_width="200dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:hint="Name"
         android:inputType="textPersonName"
         android:margin_Bottom="5dp"
         android:id="@+id/et_name"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="Phone"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:margin_Bottom="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/et_phone"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:margin_Bottom="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/et_email"/>

    <Button
        android:marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send"
        android:id="@+id/btn_send"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "android:margin_Bottom" you will want "android:layout_marginBottom".

Comment: After changing the android:margin_Bottom to "android:margin_bottom" with a lowercase b, it says : 'AAPT: error: attribute android:margin_bottom not found'